# What are the major types of effect pedals for electric guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Glossary of Guitar Effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/glossary-of-guitar-effects)

What are the major *types* of effect pedals for electric guitar?
I.e., as a novice, what effect pedal types should I be aware of, that "everybody" knows about?

Comment: I realize you could find this question subjective and a basis for discussion with no finite answer, but please help me rephrase it if you think it is not a good fit for music.SE! Or do I have to go elsewhere to get a simple answer for this?

Comment: This is very subjective, depending not only on where you are, but what type of music you listen to. It is likely to lead to a list of answers, which is not a good fit with the SE model.

Comment: @DrMayhem: Hmm. I was thinking there would be a universal list regardless of genre - hence "everybody". Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I think you may be wrong - I know I would use a very different set of pedals for blues, surf, jazz, metal, rock etc. And even the ones I would use across genres would be used in different ways.

Comment: @DrMayhem: Sure, but I'm not asking what pedals to _use_ (for any genre), nor _how_ to use them. I'd like an overview of what the most common pedal types across all genres are. I imagine it's not much more than a handful of types, such as compressor, distorsion, delay, and some others that I don't know. But I'll gladly let it go if it's perceived as an unsuitable question. :-)

Comment: I would have assumed the same as Ulf, that there are a few major *types* of pedals.  I think this would be useful info, even if it is technically a list.  If it's as unbounded as you say though @DrMayhem then I would lean towards closing it -- "Sorry, there are too many and which ones are common is very localized" is still giving an answer of sorts.

Comment: Best bet is to see how it goes then - so far I'm in a minority, so quite prepared to believe I'm only seeing a biased view :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/1838/36

Comment: @AlexBasson: Thanks! I've added the guitar-effects tag to that question now so that I find it the next time I want to ask it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To try and provide a sort of answer - for different genres, and based on the various covers bands I have played in over the years, the most common effects used (and the ones I couldn't do without) are:

**Blues:**

Fuzz, Overdrive, Delay, Wah and Reverb

**Metal:**

Distortion, Compression, Whammy/Pitchshifter, Noise Gate, Reverb

**Surf:**

Fuzz, Delay, Phaser

**Rock:**

Fuzz, Delay, Phaser, Compression, Reverb, Flanger

Quite a variety, but I'm interested if answers come to a consensus.

Comment: Wah wah too for blues (SRV, Hendrix, others).

Comment: Agreed - can't believe I forgot that one

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Dr Mayhem's answer, Alex Basson's linked possible duplicate question, and some googling I'm thinking perhaps this could be a relatively relevant list of major types (or groups) of effect pedals:

- Reverb
- Delay
- Compressor/Limiter
- Distortion/Overdrive/Fuzz
- Flanger/Phaser/Chorus
- Pitch Shifter/Harmonizer/Octave
- Niose Gate
- Boost
- Wah/Auto-Wah