# How to make Electric guitar sound like a saxophone

Tags: guitar, tone, saxophone

I'm not talking about midi or synthesizers. I have a Digitech Rp 500 processor. I want to know what settings I must do to make my guitar sound (atleast in a rough way) like  a sax.

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/how-can-i-create-a-long-sustained-note-on-an-electric-guitar/5856#5856 and http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/what-factors-affect-a-guitars-ability-to-sustain-a-note

Comment: That sounds fairly outlandish. It might help if you provided an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, of course, is to play single notes. The Sax is a single-voice instrument, and double stops will not sound sax-y.

Next, you'll have to change the attack-decay-sustain-release characteristics of the guitar to match the saxophone. The sax has sustain as long as the player has breath, and there are techniques like circular breathing that expand that. You can use an eBow to match that, but then you lose the attack. Some compression or overdrive might help here.

The opening to the Byrds' "Eight Miles High" is Roger McGuinn's attempt to transfer John Coltrane's intro to "India" to a Rickenbacker 12-string. This shows the attack that saxophones have and the difficulties in getting that on guitar, but it also segues into phrasing. Saxophone players have a way of playing that guitarists, who don't need breath control to play their instrument, find foreign.

EQing the tonal qualities should be the easiest part. Getting your guitar and fingers to behave more like a sax would be the harder challenge.

Comment: Sorry if I communicated it wrong. I didn't mean imitating the sax. Just to get that sweet tone using my processor. Thanks!

Comment: More technique ideas (unfortunately not what was wanted): fingerstyle with heavy use of the *apoyando* stroke; coordinate string changes with the size of the horn's register (ie, use a *long position*: always use fret 5 instead of an open string).

Answer (score 3):

tweak your reverb and lower your attack.

also teak your phaser:

low feedback

low depth

one third rate (hz)

half Upper (hz)

if you have a tube amp, move it to sound more warm.

play it more like single note guitar solo instead of chords or strumming.
Bend the note a bit here and there !

have fun !