# How to sustain bends and vibrato better in the guitar?

Tags: guitar-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What factors affect a guitar’s ability to sustain a note?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/what-factors-affect-a-guitars-ability-to-sustain-a-note)
>   [How to play a long sustained note on an electric guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/how-can-i-create-a-long-sustained-note-on-an-electric-guitar)

My guitar, a Washburn N2, doesn't have a good clean sound for bend and vibrato - the sound with my amplifier "dies" a lot. I tried a distortion pedal and bends sustain much better but I don't like the sound of distortion, I want it powerful and clean. Is there another effect that don`t make sound of the guitar too artificial , just clean and bright and good for bending and vibrato? My amplifier has an overdrive but is not very good either.

Answer (score 1):

A compressor pedal can add sustain to your signal without distortion.

I would also consider having your guitar set up by a professional as there are several factors of a good setup that can improve sustain such as string height and pickup height. Higher action may help sustain by preventing unwanted vibration from the string against the fretboard and lowering pickups can reduce the magnetic pull on the string allowing the string to vibrate longer. Also problems at your nut or bridge can take it's toll on sustain.