# Negative Beat / Silence

Tags: beats

Some music these days contain tiny pauses after/instead of each beat.
Hard to describe but one example I just heard is

**Petite Bisquit - Sunset Lover**

What is this effect or style called?

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly sidechain compression?
This question/answer might help: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/depression-sensation-after-the-beat-in-electronic-music/7270#7270

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the track from about 40 seconds in, where the percussion starts.  You'll see that the beat wasn't quite where you thought it was!  Starting the song with a syncopated figure against an un-stated beat gives a pleasantly ambiguous effect.  It's very much a technique of music created in a sequencer rather than conceived for live performance.  Similar to the trick where the music starts with a 'beat', layers are added and then, half way through the track there's a 'break down' to just one element.

Answer (score 0):

There is one main thing happening in this song : sidechain.

Sidechains enable composers to control the output volume of some tracks (or instruments) according to another instruments volume output. Here every single track is sidechained to the kick drum. This results in every instruments going very quiet each time the kick drum hits, creating this "tiny pause" effect. And it really is just an effect and don't really translate into musical theory terms.

Combining this effect with syncopated harmonic or melodic rhythm emphasize said syncopation.

Comment: FTR: _sidechain_ per se is not an effect. The effect you're talking about is a _ducking compressor_, whose detection (sidechain-input) happens to be controlled by an entirely different source.